# ROS catkin build - cannot find shared library

Tags: c++, linker, ros, catkin

I am trying to catkin build this ROS package https://github.com/toddhester/rl-texplore-ros-pkg but it fails to build 'rl_experiment' with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lagentlib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lenvlib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am using ROS Kinetic. The shared libraries does exist in the folders /texplore/devel/.private/rl_env/lib/ and /texplore/devel/.private/rl_agent/lib/ with symlinks at /texplore/devel/lib/

I tried the following:

(1) export /texplore/devel/lib/ to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

(2) adding symlinks to the libraries in /texplore/src/rl_experiment/src

(3) adding the library paths to target_link_libraries

```
target_link_libraries(experiment agentlib envlib ${catkin_LIBRARIES} 
    "/media/usr/texplore/devel/lib/libagentlib.so"
    "/media/usr/texplore/devel/lib/libenvlib.so")
```

(4) set the search path for linker

```
SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS 
          "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/media/usr/texplore/devel/lib/")
```

It didn't work. Lastly, I added the symlinks to /usr/local/lib and it worked. But I do not want the symlinks in this folder.

So the linker is simply not searching the build tree. My question is, why did catkin not add the linker path in catkin_LIBRARIES? I have built ROS packages before but can't wrap my head around why this particular package is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I made the following changes based on [this post](https://answers.ros.org/question/210040/catkin-build-cant-find-shared-library-from-a-dependent-package/) on ROS Answers and the below comment in the generic CMakeLists.txt file for the catkin_packages macro:

```
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
```

I did a few things to fix this...

1. Added 
   `LIBRARIES agentlib` to the `catkin_packages` macro in the `rl_agent/CMakeLists.txt` file. This makes the `agentlib` library available later to `rl_experiment`.
2. Added `LIBRARIES envlib` to the `catkin_packages` macro in the `rl_env/CMakeLists.txt` file. This makes the `envlib` library available later to `rl_experiment`.
3. Removed `agentlib` and `envlib` from the `target_link_libraries` macro in the `rl_experiment/CMakeLists.txt` file. These are not necessary.
4. Verified `rl_agent` and `rl_env` packages are listed in the `find_package` macro of the `rl_experiment/CMakeLists.txt`.

...then everything successfully compiled.

Adding snippets for further clarification...

1. rl_agent CMakeLists.TXT Changes (item 1 above):

```
    ...

    ## Declare a cpp library
    # add_library(rgbd_tools
    #   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/
    # )

    add_library(agentlib
      src/Agent/DiscretizationAgent.cc
      src/Agent/QLearner.cc
      ...
      src/newmat/newmatrm.cc
      src/newmat/newmat9.cc
    )

    ## Declare a cpp executable
    # add_executable(rgbd_tools_node src/rgbd_tools_node.cpp)

    ...
```

2. rl_env CMakeLists.txt Changes (item 2 above):

```
    ...
    ###################################
    ## catkin specific configuration ##
    ###################################
    ...
    catkin_package(
       INCLUDE_DIRS include
       LIBRARIES envlib
    #  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
       CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime
    #  DEPENDS system_lib
    )

    ...
```

3. rl_experiment CMakeLists.txt Changes (items 3 & 4 above):

```
    ...
    ## Find catkin macros and libraries
    ## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
    ## is used, also find other catkin packages
    find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
      roscpp
      std_msgs
      rl_common
      rl_env
      rl_agent
    )

    ## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
    # find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
    ...
    ## Declare a cpp executable
    # add_executable(rgbd_tools_node src/rgbd_tools_node.cpp)

    add_executable(experiment src/rl.cc)
    # target_link_libraries(experiment agentlib envlib ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
    target_link_libraries(experiment ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

    #add_executable(image_converter src/image_converter.cpp)
    ...
```

Comment: I have tried that, but it still gave the same errors.

Comment: Bummer. I've replicated this several times starting from cloning the github. I am using the latest catkin tools. Would it help if I provided my CMakeLists.txt file?

Comment: Yes, that would definitely help.

Comment: Snippets added to original answer. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Adding target_link_libraries(experiment ${catkin_LIBRARIES}) (item 3) did it for me.